# Nodejs on Azure: trigger long server computation and avoid timeout

Tags: node.js, ajax, azure, timeout, polling

I have a webapp on Nodejs hosted at Azure.
One of the forms starts a very long, highly CPU consuming computation that can take several minutes.
The naive, standard implementation ended up timing out with error 500 after the 4 minutes, default Azure value.

In order to avoid this, I implemented a poll based on http://hungtran.co/long-polling-and-websockets-on-nodejs/

On client side I have an AJAX call with a 0, infinite timeout:

```
$("#optimBtn").click(function() {
    subscribe(onMessage);

    var form = document.theForm;
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "/legs/optim");

    form.submit();
})

function subscribe(callback) {
var longPoll = function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/legs/messages',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { callback(data)  },
        complete: function() {},
        timeout: 0 // (is ms) none
       })
   }
  longPoll()
}
```

The server side uses a EventEmitter to post a message containing the result of the computation to the client :

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
var messageBus = new EventEmitter()
messageBus.setMaxListeners(100)

router.get('/messages', function(req, res) {
var addMessageListener = function(res) {
    messageBus.once('message', function(data) {
        res.json(data)
    })
}
addMessageListener(res)
})
```

And the computation part is designed not to hold the request while somethingSuperLongAsync() is working:

```
var optim_post = async function(req, res, next) { 
    somethingSuperLongAsync().then(results => {
        messageBus.emit('message', results)
    })

    res.status(200).end()
};
router.post('/optim', optim_post);
```

It works fine for short jobs : when clicking the optimBtn, the client subscribes to the server on /legs/messages, post the form onto /optim, and receives the result when it's done.
Yet the ajax call still returns a 500/timeout when the process takes more than 4 minutes.

How can I fork the long process so that it can bypass the timeout ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

replying to myself: problem solved switching to WebSockets instead of long polling with Ajax